# Is it good to NOT use an IDE for a while?

Tags: ide

Sometimes I feel I can't write a simple line of code without using an IDE (VS, NetBeans, etc.), even when I write something in Notepad or MS Word I always forget and press Ctrl+Space to use AutoComplete.

I can't remember a lot of libraries names and functions and Exceptions in the languages I am using due to the IDE's abilities and I don't know if this is a problem or not.

I want to know if there are some benefits to drop the IDE away for a while and just use a simple editor to be more strong in the language or this will make the situation worse?

Comment: I think this should go on [PR](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Subjective, should be better asked over at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try it... if you've got nothing better to do...  I'd expect it's specific to the individual.  After that - maybe go outside and mow the lawn with your teeth... that's quite hard.

Comment: I can't see the reason of this downvote!..@ James Gaunt: Stop Spamming plz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I start learning a new language, I always start by using a simple editor (mostly vi oder gedit) and switch to an IDE when the problems begin to become more complex. This way, I get a good grasp of the fundamental stuff.

Comment: I think I'll do that form now

Answer (score 7):

If you have the time and space to stop using an IDE and do a lot of manual lookups to find out the names as you code, then you might want to consider this...

However, if you are being paid to produce code to a deadline, then keep the IDE.  Knowing the names of the framework classes is nowhere near as important as knowing where to look for the information about them when you need something.  These things are getting so big, that trying to hold it all in your head is not particularly feasible (unless you're Jon Skeet).

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why having things auto complete detract from your knowledge on how to apply them in your work.  At the end of the day it is showing you the name and parameters of the function, it's not writing your program for you.  It makes you more productive in that you have to type less.  You still need to know *what* variables to use and *what* functions to call.  And if you can't quite recall the full name of that long function, you can type a few letters and look, saving you a trip to the reference library.

It's making your workday more productive, not detracting from your skills.